Get last three course with duplicate row
I use oracle as a database. I want to get the courses of last three semesters ordered by semester.
This is an example of data:
semester course userId

10       a       EM-1
8        b       EM-1
9        c       EM-1
9        h       EM-1
2        d       EM-1
2        v       EM-1
2        b       EM-1
3        c       EM-1
3        a       EM-1
3        J       EM-1
3        K       EM-1
3        M       EM-1

The correct result should be:
2        d       EM-1
2        v       EM-1
2        b       EM-1
3        c       EM-1
3        a       EM-1
3        J       EM-1
3        K       EM-1
3        M       EM-1
8        b       EM-1

I tried without success with:
SELECT * FROM 
 (
  SELECT semester, course
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY course) rno
  FROM emp
 ORDER BY course
 )
WHERE rno <= 3


You should be using DENSE_RANK() on the semester:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT e.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY semester) dr
    FROM emp e
)

SELECT semester, course, userId
FROM cte
WHERE dr <= 3
ORDER BY semester;

